# How to get pictures and videos from the posts of a page in graph api of facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the recent images/videos and text from the posts on a page on facebook. In the Graph API Explorer, I have the GET

```
https://urlOfThePageINeedRecentPostsFrom/posts?fields=picture,feed,featured_video,link&limit=5&accesstoken=myAccessToken
```

In the response I am getting the feeds but they are more than the limit 5, also inside the feed data, I am only getting the texts that are posted. I want the number of likes, links, pictures or videos attached to those as well.

Comment: Limit works fine, just tested it in Graph API Explorer with basically the same request as you have shown - returns five entries only, as asked for. (Shows an additional warning that posts don’t have a `feed` field though - remove that, it makes no sense.) _“I want the number of likes, links, pictures or videos attached to those as well”_ - well then you have to ask for those fields as well.

Comment: As you suggested, I have replaced feed with posts. I am getting an object posts with an array of data with around 20 objects inside which have the fields created_time, message and id. What I need is the likes, pictures and videos of those and not the entire page itself. I am currently getting the likes and picture of the page itself and not the individual posts.

Comment: I did not suggest you should replace it, but remove it - when you are already querying `/page-id/posts`, it makes no sense to ask for a field `feed` - posts don’t have a feed. If the limit you specify gets ignored, then maybe your parameter/query string syntax is not actually correct. _“I am currently getting the likes and picture of the page itself”_ - that should by impossible, if you are actually request `/page-id/posts` already - you are on “post level” here already by specifying that edge.